# Has asset fingerprinting changed in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I recently upgraded a Rails 4.1 app to 4.2.  When I look at the page source in development mode, all of the assets now have a fingerprint associated with them:

```
/assets/application-7d90cdd9d3a3cc2a3445c0e8b748db14.js?body=1
```

Pre 4.2 I think it used to be

```
/assets/application.js?body=1
```

Has something changed or did I miss a config setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Rails 4.2 now enables asset digests ("fingerprints") in development by default.

Here is the commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f369bcf9a0dba0a945ca6fe53343c042f54c1fcf

Why the change? It is a long story, but my understanding is that the Rails team wants development and production behavior to be more similar in order to prevent unexpected errors when deploying.

Another related change in Rails 4 is that it no longer generates assets *without* digests in production. In order to catch mistakes earlier (i.e. before you deploy to production), the development settings have been changed to match the production digest behavior.

To see why this helps, here is an example:

Suppose your code (or a jQuery plugin you're using, let's say) references an asset directly by its path, like this: `/assets/logo.png`. Before Rails 4.2, this would work perfectly fine in development. But when you deploy, surprise! `/assets/logo.png` doesn't exist. In order for it to work in production, you would need to use the `asset_path` helper to generate the correct path with the fingerprint.

By forcing you to use digests/fingerprints in development, Rails 4.2 helps surface this mistake while you are still in development. No more unpleasant surprises at deploy time.

That said, these changes are... [controversial](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49), to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered this gem: https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets

it disables the digests.

From the readme:

Just put it in your Gemfile

```
gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"
```

If you want to whitelist non-digest assets for only certain files, you can configure a whitelist like this:

```
# config/initializers/non_digest_assets.rb

NonStupidDigestAssets.whitelist += [/tinymce\/.*/, "image.png"]
```

Be sure to give either a regex that will match the right assets or the logical path of the asset in question.

Note that the logical path is what you would provide to `asset_url`, so for an image at `RAILS_ROOT/assets/images/foo.png` the logical path is `foo.png`